# How to delete only one object element inside nested array in mongoDB using expressjs?

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongoose, handlebars.js, comments

I am trying the following code to delete the comments. So what I want is that whenever I click on delete of respective comment it should get deleted. But the problem I am facing here is it deletes all the comments irrespective of clicking on any delete button. Why is it happening?

Route code for deleting the comment.

```
router.route("/deleteComment").get(function(req, res) {
  console.log("AddtasksId = "+req.query.AddtasksId + "id = "+req.query.id);
  Comments.findOneAndUpdate({'AddtasksMain.AddtasksId':req.query.AddtasksId},
  {$pull: {"AddtasksMain.$.comments":{"_id": req.query.id}}},
  function(err, deleteComments) {
    if(deleteComments) {
      console.log("Comment deleted!")
      return res.end('{"msg" : "Comment Deleted", "status" : 200}');
       }
      else {
      return res.end('{"msg" : "Comment not Deleted", "status" : 300}');
      }
  });
});
```

AJAX call:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteComments", function() {    
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    var AddtasksId = $('#submitBtn4comment').attr('data-taskId');
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/deleteComment",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      AddtasksId: AddtasksId,
      id:id
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response){
    if(response.status == 200)
    window.location.reload();
  }
  });
})
```

Comments Schema:

```
{
    "AddtasksId" : "cxlq2iqy85qy$s",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcd1ca940542e29c0b4b0c7"),
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "commentDate" : "Dec 7 2020 at 0:14",
            "comment" : "Closing it now.",
            "username" : "Michael Con",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fcd268e40542e29c0b4b0d9")
        },
       {
            "commentDate" : "Dec 9 2020 at 0:14",
            "comment" : "Close it now.",
            "username" : "Ricky K",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fcd268e40586e29c1b4b0r7")
        }
    ]
}
```

I just want to delete the say suppose only second comment by `_id:5fcd268e40586e29c1b4b0r7`
on clicking delete anchor text. But instead of deleting one comment all comments get deleted.
Please tell me what's happening wrong?

Update:

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

ClientId: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },

  AddtasksMain : [{
    AddtasksId: String,
    comments: [
      {
      username: String,
      comment: String,
      commentDate:String
    }
   ]
 }]

});
```

Comment: provided sample document is inside `AddtasksMain` array?

Comment: yes @turivishal you are right.

Comment: updated the schema as now in question please check.

Comment: try converting string id to object id `"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.id)`

Comment: I just changed the findOneUpdateOne to UpdateMany and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the `findOneUpdateOne` to `UpdateMany` and it worked.
Here is the solution with `UpdateMany`:

```
router.route("/deleteComment").get(function(req, res) {
  console.log("AddtasksId = "+req.query.AddtasksId + "id = "+req.query.id);
  Comments.updateMany({'AddtasksMain.AddtasksId':req.query.AddtasksId},
  {$pull: {"AddtasksMain.$.comments":{"_id": req.query.id}}},
  function(err, deleteComments) {
    if(deleteComments) {
      console.log("Comment deleted!")
      return res.end('{"msg" : "Comment Deleted", "status" : 200}');
       }
      else {
      return res.end('{"msg" : "Comment not Deleted", "status" : 300}');
      }
  });
});
```